# Prove is linearly independent

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Prove that that the following subset $S \subseteq V$ in the respectively specified $K$- vector space $V$ is linearly independent

**a.** $K=R$, $ V=R[x] $, $S$= {$x^n-x^m| n,m ∈ R,$ n-even, m-odd}

Comment: What did you try? Where is your self work?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to solve this would be to ask yourself the following questions:

- When is a polynomial $\sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^i$ equal to the zero element or zero polynomial?
- If there were no restrictions on $n$ and $m$, then for $n=m$ the element $x^n-x^n$ would be in $S$. Is this element linearly independent (as a set with one element) hint: look at the definition of linear independence!

Then proceed by the definition of linear independence elements, i.e. write down a (finite) linear combination of elements in $S$ e.g. $\sum \lambda_i s_i, s_i \in S$ and argue that if this element should be zero, it is necessary that all $\lambda_i$ are zero already. Some step in your argumentation might be, that this sum is of course a polynomial and hence can be written in some standard form.

Good Luck